# the css code for my navigation bar does not cover the entire width of my screen. it stops about 10 pixels before the edges

Tags: html, css

I do not understand how it happened, I am still learning and tried getting rid of all the margins but nothing worked. please send your thoughts and suggestions. some of the background colors of the other elements(which I put in the CSS under the body{} tag) seem to color this empty space.

```css
@font-face {
  src:url(fonts/Staatliches-Regular.ttf);
  font-family: rust;
}
  *{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: rust;
  }

  body{
      background-color: #6588AB;
  }

  #sad{
    font-style: italic;
  }

  nav{

    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  ul{
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

  ul li{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 100px;
  }

  ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 100px 30px 100px;
  }

  ul li a:hover{
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link  rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav id = "link">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pain.html" target="_blank">about me</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_9e0_Fdaek" target="_blank">what i do</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1u-9YqrIJc" target="_blank">why i'm based</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w9hK8mh9-g" target="_blank">contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class = "pog">hello!!!</h1>
    <h2 class = "pog" id ="sadge" title="pog u">pog</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the `body` tag has margins on sides. That seems to be the issue in your case.

```
body: {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can even use `normalize.css` for resetting these styles without completely removing each and every style. Refer [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) GitHub repo.